# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php type while making contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a contact form. When I submitted from my local host using Chrome, I'm re-directed to a page that simply displays the php code. The console reads as following: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/php: "file:///Users/sheenavasani/Desktop/practice_php/mail.php". What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">

<p>Request Phone Call:</p>
Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call"><br />
No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call"><br />

<p>Website</p> <input type="text" name="website">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Website Update</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">New Products</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "YOUREMAIL@HERE.COM";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you dont have a server running?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PHP running on your machine? Make sure you have installed PHP, for example XAMPP. The code looks okey, tho. There is problem with machine misconfiguration.

Comment: I did not! Thank you!!!

Comment: @SheenaVasani you can tick the green ✓ under at my answer if it helped you. Have a great day